# Displaying data using $_POST

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have working code, but i'm have a question about sending data through $_POST that is formatted in a table.

On PAGE1.php, I have this code:

```
$printoutput .="<tr><td width='10%'> Item #". ($i+1) ."</td></tr> 
<tr width='20%'><td>  " . $product_name . " --&nbsp;$" . $price . ".00</td></tr>
<tr><td width='40%'>" . $displayoptions . "</td>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
```

It is submitted through a form, and I use POST to grab the data. On PAGE2.php, when I pull the data through and echo it out, the format is changed completely. In other words, on PAGE1.php the data looks like this:

Item #1
Hamburger -- $6.00
Fruit Cup

Item #2
Pan Roasted Salmon -- $18.00
Vegtables

**and on the second page, the data looks like this:**

Item #1
Hamburger -- $6.00
Fruit Cup

Item #2
Pan Roasted Salmon -- $18.00
Vegtables

Does anyone know how I can send over the data with the correct formatting? So when it gets to PAGE2.php, I can simply echo out the variable of data and have it displayed the same as on PAGE1.php

I've tried multiple ways to get it to work, but none of it has been correct. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

PAGE2.php code looks like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['order'])) {
  $order = $_POST['order'];
}

echo $order;
```

Comment: Sidenote: *"and I use `&_POST` to grab the data."* That ampersand is like 2-3 inches away from the `$` - You sure about that?

Comment: sorry about that typo

Comment: No problemo. No permanent damage; just checking ;-)

Comment: What do you have for code in page 2? That's what we need to see.

Comment: Updated it. I just grab the hidden input data with the value of $printoutput on page1.php, with the name of order. When it goes to the second page, I just echo it out, and the data is output it loses its formatting from page1.php @Fred -ii-

Comment: Why not just put the code that you have in page 1, and put it inside your conditional statement in page 2? Or something close to it. I'd probably be able to figure it out, but by the time I'm done, somebody's bound to put in an answer ;-)

Comment: I was planning on using the mail() function in page2.php. I'd like to just use the post method if possible, and in the mail function set my message to $order.

Comment: Have a look at what I posted below. It uses [`sessions`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

Comment: It may even be easier if you set everything inside the same page, and use conditional statements that would then trigger the `mail()` function if everything is set. I may even have another idea using sessions.

Comment: just for clarification, the changes you mentioned from `page 1` to `page 2` is just the missing **<br />** on the second page?

Comment: How are you posting a *table* to another page? And why are there `<br />` tags in the first place?

Comment: Someone edited my code so it is now displaying the <br />. I had just added those to show how the data was displayed. Sorry, still trying to learn how to create a decent question/post.

Comment: Ok, check my **Edit** - I think that should do the trick @user3150191

Comment: I will do a rollback to your original post. @user3150191

Comment: didn't you miss to put `<table></table>` tags ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

Alternate way, a chained method which will produce the same output as my original answer:

**Quick Note:**

This:

```
$_SESSION['prodname'] = $product_name = "Product name";
```

Could be changed to:

```
$_SESSION['prodname'] = $product_name = $_POST['product_name'];
```

Taking the information from your POST variable(s). The above were used as a simple test.

**Page 1**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['prodname'] = $product_name = "Product name";
$_SESSION['prodcost'] = $price = "10";
$_SESSION['display'] = $displayoptions = "Display options";

// testing purposes only
// $price = $_SESSION['prodcost'];
// $displayoptions = $_SESSION['display'];

$printoutput .="<table><tr><td width='10%'> Item #". ($i+1) ."</td></tr> 
<tr width='20%'><td>  " . $_SESSION['prodname'] . " --&nbsp;$" . $_SESSION['prodcost'] . ".00</td></tr>
<tr><td width='40%'>" . $_SESSION['display'] . "</td>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>";

// echo $printoutput;
$_SESSION['order'] = $printoutput;
echo $_SESSION['order']; // will echo on screen
```

**Page 2**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['order'])) {
// $order = $_POST['order'];

$_SESSION['order'] = $printoutput;

$printoutput .="<table><tr><td width='10%'> Item #". ($i+1) ."</td></tr> 
<tr width='20%'><td>  " . $_SESSION['prodname'] . " --&nbsp;$" . $_SESSION['prodcost'] . ".00</td></tr>
<tr><td width='40%'>" . $_SESSION['display'] . "</td>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>";

echo $printoutput; // Successfully printed out data from page 1
}

// You can place the mail() function below this
```

---

#### Original answer

You could use [**sessions**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) for this.

Being limited with unshown code, have come up with the following:

**N.B.:** I added `<table>` and `</table>` tags as my own test.

**Page 1**

```
<?php
session_start();
$product_name = "Product name";
$price = "10";
$displayoptions = "Display options";

$printoutput .="<table><tr><td width='10%'> Item #". ($i+1) ."</td></tr> 
                            <tr width='20%'><td>  " . $product_name . " --&nbsp;$" . $price . ".00</td></tr>
                            <tr><td width='40%'>" . $displayoptions . "</td>
                            <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>";

$_SESSION['order'] = $printoutput;
echo $_SESSION['order'];
```

**Page 2**

**N.B.:** `echo $_SESSION['order'];` may need to be moved inside your conditional statement, yet the following works in the position it's in now.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['order'])) {
  $order = $_POST['order'];
}

echo $_SESSION['order'];
```

which will print:

Item #1
Product name -- $10.00
Display options

The HTML source produced:

```
<table><tr><td width='10%'> Item #1</td></tr> 
<tr width='20%'><td>  Product name --&nbsp;$10.00</td></tr>
<tr><td width='40%'>Display options</td>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
```